# Android Developemnt: Decrease horizontal swipe sensitivity OR turn off vertical swiping

Tags: java, android, swipe

I am building an app that allows the user to navigate through different screens using horizontal swipes, however these screens also contain a vertical scrollview. It appears that android detects vertical scrolling as horizontal swipes if the vertical scroll isn't 100% vertical (hope that makes sense).

Is there anyway to disable vertical swiping, or decrease the sensitivity of the horizontal detection?

The code within the onFling class is pretty basic at the moment like so.

```
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent start, MotionEvent finish, float velocityX,
                float velocityY) {
     //Right Swipe
     if (finish.getRawX() < start.getRawX()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Showing Listings For : "+date.getDate(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }

     if (start.getRawX() < finish.getRawX()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Showing Listings For : "+date.getDate(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
    }
```

**-- Update --**

Well I ended up calculating the vertical difference bewtween the start and end points of the swipe, which gave me a something to use to determine how vertical a swipe was. Its pretty basic but seems to work ok.

The updated code now looks like.

```
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent start, MotionEvent finish, float velocityX,
                float velocityY) {
     //Right Swipe

     //Caluclate the vertical difference
     float verticalChange = start.getRawY() - finish.getRawY();

     if ((finish.getRawX() < start.getRawX()) && (verticalChange > -40 && verticalChange < 40)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Showing Listings For : "+date.getDate(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }

     if (start.getRawX() < finish.getRawX()) && (verticalChange > -40 && verticalChange < 40)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Showing Listings For : "+date.getDate(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You could extend your own vertical scrollview that does not trigger the event for a horizontal swipe. Of course, then you would have to swipe on a part that is not the scroll view.

--Extra Comment ---Have you tested this on various phones/devices? You may find yourself having different results.

Comment: Ideally I would like the whole screen to be swipeable, but only in the horizontal plane. No I have only tested on emulators so far.

Comment: I'd suggest trying it on an actual phone if possible (may borrow a friends?) and seeing if you have the same results.

The emulator has come a long way, but if you have a slower computer, its results can be rather wonky/awkward I've found.